# Difficulty malloc'ing additional memory?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I have this "array" of pointers to structures initially allocated by a malloc, and I need to add additional memory by an increment when the initial capacity becomes full.  When I try to allocate more memory, the first element seems to vanish and causes my program to crash.  Can anyone help?

```
#include "a2.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int idCompare ( const void * a, const void * b ){
    message *m1 = *(message **)a;
    message *m2 = *(message **)b;
    return m1->messageId - m2->messageId;     
}

int textCompare( const void *a, const void *b ) {
    message *m1 = *(message **)a;
    message *m2 = *(message **)b;
    return strcmp(m1->messageText, m2->messageText);
}

int main(void)
{   
    int id, i;
    int count = 0;

    char cmd[MAX_CMD_LEN];
    char msg_text[MAX_TEXT_LEN];
    message **mList = malloc(INITIAL_CAPACITY * sizeof(message));
    int capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY * sizeof(message);
    int size = 0;

    while (scanf("%s", cmd)){

        if (!strcmp(cmd, "add")){
            printf("(pre) Capacity =%d, Count =%d, Size =%d\n", capacity, count, size);
            int found = 0;
            scanf("%d\n", &id);
            fgets(msg_text, sizeof(msg_text), stdin);

            if(size >= capacity){
                capacity = size;
                *(mList + count) = malloc(CAPACITY_INCREMENT * sizeof(message));
                message *p = *(mList + count);                    
                if(p == NULL){                                          //If malloc fails, free mList and exit.
                    printf("out of memory\n");
                    free(*mList);
                    exit(1);
                }
            }   

            for(i = 0; i < count; i++){                                 //If existing id is found, send flag & do not add.
                message *p = *(mList + i);
                if(p->messageId == id){  found = 1;  }
            }

            if(!found){                                                
                message *p = *(mList + count);          
                p->messageId = id;
                p->messageText = malloc(strlen(msg_text)+1);    
                strcpy(p->messageText, msg_text);           
                count++;      
                size += 10 * sizeof(message);
                printf("(post) Capacity =%d, Count =%d, Size =%d\n", capacity, count, size);
            }
        }

        else if (!strcmp(cmd, "delete")){                       //Cycle through mList, if id is found, shift elements left.
        scanf("%d", &id);
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){                
            message *p = *(mList + i);
                if(p->messageId == id){  
                    for(;i < count; i++){*(mList + i) = *(mList + i + 1);}
                    count--;
                    size -= 10 * sizeof(message); 
                }
            }  
        }

        else if (!strcmp(cmd, "find")){                                 //Cycle through mList, if id is matched, print to stdout.
        scanf("%d", &id);
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){              
            message *p = *(mList + i);
                if(p->messageId == id){  printf("%s", p->messageText);  }
            } 
        }

        else if (!strcmp(cmd, "output")){                       //Cycle through mList, print all to stdout.
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
            message *p = *(mList + i);
                printf("%s", p->messageText);
            }
        }

        else if (!strcmp(cmd, "sortById")){  qsort (mList, count, sizeof(message*), idCompare);  }

        else if (!strcmp(cmd, "sortByText")){  qsort (mList, count, sizeof(message*), textCompare);  }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See also [SO 5228200](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228200/qsorting-a-mallocd-array-of-structures).  This is a different question, but the same data structures.

Comment: You might want to draw a picture of your mList structure and the operations you're doing on it, because what you're doing now is incoherent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, your message list consists of

```
message **mList
```

yet you are not using it as a pointer to a list of pointers. You never allocate the pointers in the list!

For example, this would be "correct" (though inefficient):

```
message **mList = malloc(INITIAL_CAPACITY * sizeof(message*));
for (i = 0; i < INITIAL; i++) {
   mList[i] = malloc(sizeof(message));
}
```

Now you have the data structure you've expressed.

However, you could also perform:

```
message *mList = malloc(INITIAL_CAPACITY * sizeof(message));
```

In all cases, once you have fixed your memory access problems,  you can use `realloc()` to resize in place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `realloc()` to make an allocated memory block larger.

`realloc()` will allocate a new block (if needed), copy the original data over to the new block, and free the old block (if needed).

If you just call `malloc()` again, you allocate a new memory block with new values. It also means you've created a memory leak because your original memory block doesn't get freed.

Answer (score 0):

At least from the looks of things, you're defining `mlist` incorrectly:

```
message **mList = malloc(INITIAL_CAPACITY * sizeof(message));
```

Since you're allocating the space for the `message` structures, it looks like `mList` should just be a `message *`:

```
message *mList = malloc(INITIAL_CAPACITY * sizeof(message));
```

or (what I usually prefer):

```
message *mList = malloc(INITIAL_CAPACITY * sizeof(*mList));
```

Overall, your code seems to be confusing two rather different cases. One is that you're dynamically allocating an array of `message`s, and the other is that you're allocating an array of pointers to messages. Though the question isn't an exact duplicate, I previously posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950860/assigning-an-address-to-a-struct-pointer-array-member-in-c/3950982#3950982) with diagrams to show the difference graphically.

While the other answers are correct that `realloc` is generally useful for expanding an allocation, I think you need to do a bit more thinking about what you're expanding: an array of `message`s, or an array of pointers, with each actual `message` allocated individually. From the looks of things, your `message` structure itself contains a pointer to things like the actual text of the message, which is allocated separately from the `message` structure itself. That being the case, it *probably* makes more sense to allocate an array of message objects rather than an array of pointers.